# Converting Html to PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Can anyone help me converting Html to PHP

I want to add a paypal button to my woocommerce website but I am running into a few errors.

here is the code I have in html format

```
<a class="paypal_checkout_button" href="websitelinkhere"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" width="145" height="42" style="width: 145px; height: 42px; padding-top: 30px; padding-left:20px; " border="0" align="top" alt="Check out with PayPal"></a>
```

Basically im using the theme - theretailer.getbowtied.com/demo the shopping cart dropdown at the top of the main page im trying to add the button into that but cant get it to display
Any help would be amazing

Edit*

this is the page im trying to add the code to

```
 <div class="gbtr_minicart_wrapper">
 <div class="gbtr_minicart">

<?php echo '<a class="paypal_checkout_button" href="websitelinkhere"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" width="145" height="42" style="width: 145px; height: 42px; padding-top: 30px; padding-left:20px; " border="0" align="top" alt="Check out with PayPal"></a>';?>

<?php                                    
echo '<ul class="cart_list">';                                        
if (sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents)>0) : foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) :

 $_product = $cart_item['data'];                                            
 if ($_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity']>0) :                                            
      echo '<li class="cart_list_product">';                                                
      echo '<a class="cart_list_product_img" href="'.get_permalink($cart_item['product_id']).'">' . $_product->get_image().'</a>';                                                    
      echo '<div class="cart_list_product_title">';
      $gbtr_product_title = $_product->get_title();
      //$gbtr_short_product_title = (strlen($gbtr_product_title) > 28) ? substr($gbtr_product_title, 0, 25) . '...' : $gbtr_product_title;
      echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($cart_item['product_id']).'">' . apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_widget_product_title', $gbtr_product_title, $_product) . '</a>';
       echo '<div class="cart_list_product_quantity">'.__('Quantity:', 'theretailer').' '.$cart_item['quantity'].'</div>';
       echo '</div>';
       echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s">&times;</a>', esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ), __('Remove this item', 'woocommerce') ), $cart_item_key );
       echo '<div class="cart_list_product_price">'.woocommerce_price($_product->get_price()).'</div>';
       echo '<div class="clr"></div>';                                                
       echo '</li>';                                         
       endif;                                        
      endforeach;
?>

<div class="minicart_total_checkout">                                        
<?php _e('Cart subtotal', 'theretailer'); ?><span>
<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></span>                                   
</div>


<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" class="button gbtr_minicart_cart_but"><?php _e('View Shopping Bag', 'theretailer'); ?></a>   
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url() ); ?>" class="button gbtr_minicart_checkout_but"><?php _e('Proceed to Checkout', 'theretailer'); ?></a>

  <?php                                        
  else: echo '<li class="empty">'.__('No products in the cart.','woocommerce').'</li>'; endif;                                    
   echo '</ul>';                                    
   ?>                                                                        

   </div>
   </div>

   </div>

  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" class="gbtr_little_shopping_bag_wrapper_mobiles"><span><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count; ?></span></a>

   </div>
```

Im looking for it to go under the buttons

Im looking for it to go into the gbtr_minicart section under the buttons

Comment: `echo '<a class="paypal_checkout_button" href="websitelinkhere"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" width="145" height="42" style="width: 145px; height: 42px; padding-top: 30px; padding-left:20px; " border="0" align="top" alt="Check out with PayPal"></a>'`?

Comment: what kind of problems? Do you have any experience with php?

Comment: Could you explain more about what you want to achieve with this? You can't really convert html to php, you can echo it etc. Could you show more of the page you are using this on? Is the rest of the page in php?

Comment: Basically im using the theme - http://theretailer.getbowtied.com/demo/ the shopping cart dropdown at the top im trying to add the button into that but cant get it to display =/

Comment: Ok, could you show the code you are wanting to add the button to? It may not be a php issue but an html/css one.

Comment: Added the code there now for you

Comment: What are the errors?  You don't need to add this as PHP at all, it's just html and you've added it into the correct place.  I can add it in like you have via the dev tools in that theme demo and the paypal button appears no probs. See -> http://www.mcnab.co/bowtied.jpg

Comment: Hey McNab Those section of the theme are all built using php and when I add it in it doesnt appear.

Answer (score 4):

here you go

```
//some php code
?>
    <a class="paypal_checkout_button" href="websitelinkhere"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" width="145" height="42" style="width: 145px; height: 42px; padding-top: 30px; padding-left:20px; " border="0" align="top" alt="Check out with PayPal"></a>
<?php
//php code again
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  echo '<a class="paypal_checkout_button" href="websitelinkhere"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" width="145" height="42" style="width: 145px; height: 42px; padding-top: 30px; padding-left:20px; " border="0" align="top" alt="Check out with PayPal"></a>';

?>
```